# unrecognized option -keypass while getting MD5 Fingerprint of Debug Certificate for Google Maps API Key

Tags: android, google-maps, keytool

i used linux ubuntu 10.10....... my android debug.keystore is in the location `~/.android/debug.keystore`.

i used the following terminal commands as explained in http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

```
rakib@rakib-laptop:~/.android$ \
> keytool -list \
> -alias androiddebugkey \
> -keystore "~/.android/debug.keystore" \
> -storepass android \
> -keypass android
```

and it returns the following error

```
list: unrecognized option '-keypass'
list: Try 'list -help' for more information
```

i have no idea why this is not recognizing the option -keypass....... EVERYONE else is using this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, thanks to a series of quick participation at [StackOverflow.com](http://goo.gl/b7slO) and at [Android-Developer-googleGroup](http://goo.gl/FFYHp), now the solution is clear..... let me give a rundown of how I resolved it, **in case any of you are having a similar problem**.

my android developer **debug.keystore** file is in the following location in my linux

```
~/.android/debug.keystore
```

then i `cd ~` and followed the steps as mentioned in the Google Projects for Android page for [Obtaining a Maps API Key](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html#getdebugfingerprint) to get the md5 fingerprint of my debug.keystore

```
rakib@rakib-laptop:~$ \
> keytool \
> -list \
> -alias androiddebugkey \
> -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore \
> -storepass android \
> -keypass android
```

but it returned a stupid frustrating error

```
list: unrecognized option '-keypass'
list: Try 'list -help' for more information
```

and that's when i started all the forums and discussions etc. but didn't find the right solution. After several forum posts, I figured that my simple call to **keytool** is referring to ***an unwanted keytool - a keytool that appears to be from the GNU Compiler for Java. Android rather requires the keytool from Sun/Oracle Java***

Hence, i did the following to find out all the instance of different keytool programs that i have in my linux system.

```
rakib@rakib-laptop:~$ locate keytool
```

and it gave me the following list

```
/etc/alternatives/keytool
/etc/alternatives/keytool.1.gz
/home/rakib/java-WTK-2.5.2/bin/mekeytool
/usr/bin/gkeytool-4.4
/usr/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4/jre/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-4.4/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/bin/keytool
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/man/ja/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/man/ja/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/gkeytool-4.4.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man1/keytool.1.gz
/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/keytool
```

Bingo!!! so many keytool instances have been located. now I need to use the one in Java-6-sun JRE.
So, ***cd*** to that directory as found from the **locate keytool** command above

```
rakib@rakib-laptop:~$ cd /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/bin/
```

now that the terminal is inside the ***java-6-sun/jre/bin*** directory, i typed the following command - remember that my debug.keystore file was in **~/.android/debug.keystore** ?

```
rakib@rakib-laptop:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/bin$ \
> ./keytool \
> -list -alias androiddebugkey \
> -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore \
> -storepass android \
> -keypass android
```

and voila..... that returned the MD5 fingerprint of my android debug certificate that i was looking for.

```
androiddebugkey, Mar 19, 2011, PrivateKeyEntry, 
Certificate fingerprint (MD5): 08:A6:77:9C:97:66:CA:00:B9:6B:82:6B:37:64:B8:14
```

Notice that when i was typing keytool command from the java-6-sun/jre/bin folder, you **must not write JUST "keytool"**. you **must instead write "./keytool"** - with a period and a slash to imply that you are referring to the keytool inside **the current directory** where the terminal is.

```
rakib@rakib-laptop:~$ WooooooHooooooooooooooo!!!!!
```

***PostNote:*** this problem of executing the wrong keytool was happening because my java-6-sun JRE was not the **default java environment** in my ubuntu. rather my GNU java compiler was set as the default java environment. in order to change the default Java environment in your linux machine, see the [Ubuntu Community Help for Java](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java)

Answer (score 2):

Your `keytool` appears to be from the GNU Compiler for Java. Android requires the Sun/Oracle Java, though OpenJDK may work for you as well. Try using the `keytool` from a supported Java environment.

Comment: how do i use the keytool from a supported Java environment??? where or how to get it?

Comment: @syedrakib: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing.html -- you should have done this before writing a single line of code for an Android project.

Comment: okay........ **now it seems to have worked out**..... thanks @CommonsWare for the pointer. i cannot put in the code snippet in this comment field because code snippets in comment field of StackOverflow doesn't appear nice..... so the **terminal code snippet is given below** as an answer to my question. kindly rate the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: i did this thing before writing a single line of code.... somehow a simple call to 'keytool' from my linux terminal was pointing to the GNU keytool........ but a call to '/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.24/jre/bin/keytool' was pointing to the desired Java supported keytool that you mentioned above...... do you know how to make the Java supported keytool the default keytool? so that when i am using the keyword 'keytool' from the terminal, it points to the java supported keytool rather than the GNU keytool. 
**we are all learning here bro**

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .android/debug.keystore
```

You have not insert a pwd if it isn't configured.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i typed what you said... now it gave me another error

`> keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "debug.keystore"`
`> Enter key store password: 123`
`> keytool error: gnu.javax.crypto.keyring.MalformedKeyringException: incorrect magic`

Comment: when ask you for pwd simply press return. Have you set a pwd?

Comment: now i did **not** put any password - simple pressed return. again it returned the same keytool error

Answer (score 0):

You all are missing the fact that this is a documentation bug.

Keytool's -list command *does not accept* the -keypass argument. It is not needed, as -list does not access the private key in any way.

If you call 'keytool' with no arguments, it tells you:

-list        [-v | -rfc] [-protected]
             [-alias ]
             [-keystore ] [-storepass ]
             [-storetype ] [-providername ]
             [-providerclass  [-providerarg ]] ...
             [-providerpath ]

Note: no -keypass

This is a documentation bug at: http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/mapkey.html

The reason it works when you switch to using Sun/Oracle's keytool is that version does not signal an error in this case. But as you can see above -- it also specifically does not use it.

Public key cryptography is based on standards. So long as any tool can access Java's non-standard keystore format (or if you use a standard one such as PKCS12), you should be able to use that tool for any task involving actual signing, and any MD5 fingerprint you can coax a tool to show you should be equivalent.

Don't supply bogus arguments, and you should be fine with whatever keytool you end up with.

Edit: Note that it DOES accept the -storepass argument. If you have encrypted your entire keystore, and you don't supply the encryption password, then it will not understand your keystore and you'll get an error.  You can supply it either with -storepass *password* or you can supply it on the command line when prompted. Just typing Enter when a password has been set will of course not work.

By contrast, -keypass supplies the password for a private key. It is used only in commands that actually access the private key, such as for signing.